# Rails Engine + Mongoid: No configuration could be found for a session named 'default'

Tags: rails-engines, mongoid3

I've created a Rails Mountable App and added 'mongoid' and 'rspec' gem's. If I try to run my specs now I get the following error:

```
Mongoid::Errors::NoSessionConfig: 
Problem:
  No configuration could be found for a session named 'default'.
Summary:
  When attempting to create the new session, Mongoid could not find a session configuration for the name: 'default'. This is necessary in order to know the host, port, and options needed to connect.
Resolution:
  Double check your mongoid.yml to make sure under the sessions key that a configuration exists for 'default'. If you have set the configuration programatically, ensure that 'default' exists in the configuration hash.
```

When I add the `Mongoid.load!(Rails.root.join("config", "mongoid.yml"))` line to `spec_helper.rb` everything works normal.

Why is that and how can I get the functionality like in a normal Rails app where I don't need to call the load function?

***mongoid.yml***

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: dummy_development
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
  options:
test:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: dummy_test
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        consistency: :strong
        max_retries: 1
        retry_interval: 0
```

***Versions:***

```
gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.12'
gem 'mongoid', '~> 3.1'
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.13'
```

Comment: Can you post your mongoid.yml file?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you probably missed `require 'rails/mongoid'` in your spec_helper.rb file.

Had someone having the same issue in here https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/2894#issuecomment-14903927

Try adding that require, that should fix it.

Comment: Where do I find that `spec_helper.rb` file?

Comment: I found in the `Echo` sample project for mongoid+rails, and I didn't have the `spec` folder in my generated app folder

Comment: spec_helper.rb is generated by rspec, if you're not using rspec, put it on your application.rb

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me on my machine

1: Add this to your config/application.rb

```
Mongoid.load!("path to your mongoid.yml")
```

2: And change your mongoid.yml from (Only for mongoid version < 5):

This

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      database: database_for_development
        hosts:
          - localhost:27017
test:
  clients:
    default:
      database: database_for_test
        hosts:
          - localhost:27017
production:
  clients:
    default:
      database: database_for_production
        hosts:
          - localhost:27017
```

To:

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: database_for_development
        hosts:
          - localhost:27017
test:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: database_for_test
        hosts:
          - localhost:27017
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: database_for_production
        hosts:
          - localhost:27017
```

Comment: Rails 4.2.7.1 had issue in locating/understanding `mongoid.yml` file when installing and configuring mongoid. `mongoid.yml` file was generated successfully but was not recognized. #1 worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably because of two simultaneous conditions: ( there is no production section in mongoid.yml ) AND ( Heroku treats Rails applications as production by default ).

Fixing either one shall suffice.

**1. There is no production section in mongoid.yml**

Add production section to mongoid.yml, as explained at [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongohq#use-with-ruby) , e.g.

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
      options:
        skip_version_check: true
        safe: true
```

**2. Heroku treats rails applications as production by default**

Set Heroku environment to development, or a add a new environment which would be specific to Heroku, as explained at [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments#managing-staging-and-production-configurations), e.g.

```
heroku config:set RACK_ENV=development RAILS_ENV=development --remote development
```

Answer (score 2):

And restart the server after making changes to mongoid.yml

Answer (score 1):

I've found this working - notice there is no "sessions", only "clients"

```
production:
  clients:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGODB_URI'] %>
      options:
        skip_version_check: true
        safe: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to regenerate a new `mongoid.yml`:

`rails g mongoid:config`

And after change `mongoid.yml` with your values.